# Bug when I press the button with invokemember () Webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

If I enter the credentials in a login and I manually press the button it makes me access the site without problems, otherwise if I use the method InvokeMember ("click");

It tells me incorrect credentials, even if they are right.

Example

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("").InvokeMember("click");
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit"))
    {
        el.InvokeMember("onclick");

    }
}
```

I wait for the access to be done correctly, like when I press the button manually, even entering the credentials with GetElementById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

First, get the submit button if you have ID. Then check whether it is exit or not

```
HtmlElement htmlElement = automationWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("submitBtnRight");
if (htmlElement != null)
{
  htmlElement.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

If possible post your button HTML

Comment: <input id="submitBtnRight" type="submit" class="btn-login" onclick="document.forms['loginFormElement'].submit();return false;" value="LOGIN">

Comment: I have changed the button ID now try the code. I hope it will work.